# Update in MySQL from Node.js - How to tell if zero rows are effected?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am querying a mySQL database from the context of Node.js server code. Generally speaking, things are working fine. However, I can't figure out a way to tell whether an UPDATE statement does not update any rows. For instance, if I have code such as:

```
connection.query("UPDATE table SET columnA = valA WHERE columnB = valB;",
    function(err, rows, fields) {

   ..some code..
}
```

As far as I can tell, none of the callbacks (err, rows, fields) will provide me with any information informing me that zero rows were affected. This is important information to me. How can I resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I assume you're using node-mysql. The count of changed rows is in `result.changedRows` variable.

Try:

```
connection.query('UPDATE table SET ...', function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('changed ' + result.changedRows + ' rows');
});
```

You can also get `result.affectedRows`.

Further info is within [the docs](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql).

Comment: Thanks Dirk. The function(err, result) callback is what I was needing. Enjoy your weekend!