# Mysql Rollback Transaction if Insert Into Select fails

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables - table1, table2, relation_table1_table2. To insert a row into table2 I am running a transaction like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 ..... ;

SET @table2_insert_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();\

INSERT INTO relation_table1_table2 (table1_id, table2_id)
SELECT id, @table2_insert_id FROM table2
WHERE table1.column1 = 'ABC';
```

What if the id in table1 does not exist and the nested Select is null. How to make this transaction fail in that scenario? Cant do stored procedure.

Comment: No it didn"t because it is no error

Comment: What is `GET LAST_INSERT_ID` supposed to be? The correct syntax is something like `SET @variable = LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Comment: Just updated the question the correct syntax. It was just to give the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `ROW_COUNT()` after the `INSERT` to get the number of rows inserted. If it's zero, raise an error.

```
IF ROW_COUNT() == 0
THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Nothing found to insert';
END IF;
```

If you can't use SQL conditional statements, do the condition in JavaScript.

```
db.query(`INSERT INTO relation_table1_table2 (table1_id, table2_id)
          SELECT id, @table2_insert_id FROM table2
          WHERE table1.columnX = 'ABC'`, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        throw "Query failed";
    }
    if (res.affectedRows == 0) {
        db.rollback();
        throw "Nothing inserted";
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont think that can be used in a AWS Lambda Nodejs function.

Comment: Can you check in JavaScript instead of SQL?

Comment: There's nothing in the question about AWS Lambda. Since you're executing multiple statements, I assumed it was in a stored procedure.

Comment: There were so many edits on this one that I was going to delete and post it fresh. Anyway thanks for responding. Yeah not a stored procedure.

Comment: I've added JS code to perform the check.

Comment: Ok got what you are doing. That will work. Thanks

Comment: affectedRows instead of changedRows

Comment: I got it from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227458/update-in-mysql-from-node-js-how-to-tell-if-zero-rows-are-effected). In this case, I think either should work.

Comment: They only differ for `UPDATE` statements or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. If you set a row to the same values it already has, `affectedRows` counts it, `changedRows` doesn't.